# Preposition: its peak is (at) by the end of a/the day

Tags: grammar, prepositions, phrases

What is the correct **preposition** and **phrase** here:

[image]

> Overall, the highest number in terms of consumption of energy is in winter and its **peak** is **by the end of THE day** in England

Vs.

> Overall, the highest number in terms of consumption of energy is in winter and its **peak** is **AT by the end of A day** in England.

Please help, I am flummoxed here as you can see.

Comment: It should be *and its peak is **reached** (by / at) the end of the day.* And either preposition works. (Although the sentence as a whole still sounds a bit odd, even with that correction.)

Comment: Do have a suggestion to improve the constructed sentence?

Answer (score 1):

While **both are correct** (-ish), your first option is unclear and may often be misinterpreted.

You are using [Merriam-Webster's](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/by) first definition:

> **1:** in proximity to : near

However, definition **3b** can also be used in a valid interpretation of the sentence:

> **3b:** not later than
>
> // *be there by 2 p.m.*

Using this definition, the sentence would mean that consumption reaches its peak at any time before the end of the day - which evaluates to *any time during the day*. While this results in a fairly meaningless sentence, and thus many people will be able to determine what you intended to convey, it is also the more common definition in the context of timeframes, and will cause unnecessary confusion.

Therefore, **the second option is more clear**. It is, however, slightly incorrect - it should be written:

> Overall, the highest number in terms of consumption of energy is in winter and its peak is at the end of the day in England.

It also reads somewhat strangely; I might suggest altering it to something like:

> Overall, energy consumption in England is greatest in winter, with daily consumption reaching its peak at 10:00 pm.

Note that this assumes "in England" refers to the location (which is unclear in the original). If it instead refers to the time zone, that would preferably be specified.

Additionally, "end of the day" is potentially vague, especially in winter - it may refer to the end of daylight hours or midnight. I recommend using a specific time if possible.

Comment: From what you have written, "Using this definition, the sentence would mean that consumption reaches its peak **at any time** before the end of the day* - which evaluates to any time during the day". I don't think so, I didn't write **before** the end of the day (which has a meaning of at any time before the end of the day) but **by the end of the day** instead, which means **close** to the end of the day. Right?

Comment: I suppose the definition is precise, but there might be some misinterpretations here...

Comment: @JohnArvin **by** can mean **before** or **close to** when applied to timeframes, which is why there's a danger of misunderstanding. Granted, even in the prior meaning, there's a connotation of closer to the event than not - for example, if I were to be told "It's likely to start raining by sunset" I'd expect rain in the afternoon or evening, not morning - but there's still ambiguity that using **at** avoids.